# Parse JSON from CURL output using python

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

I am trying to get value of id i.e. **"id": 59** which is in the curl output in form of json.
Below is the curl output in json:

```
[{"id":59,"description":"This is a demo project","name":"Demo_Project","name_with_namespace":"sam / Demo_Project","path":"demo_project","path_with_namespace":"sam/demo_project","created_at":"2020-03-02T08:43:13.664Z","default_branch":"master","tag_list":[],"ssh_url_to_repo":"ssh://git@od-test.od.com:2222/sam/demo_project.git","http_url_to_repo":"https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/sam/demo_project.git","web_url":"https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/sam/demo_project","readme_url":"https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/sam/demo_project/blob/master/README.md","avatar_url":null,"star_count":0,"forks_count":0,"last_activity_at":"2020-04-09T09:28:09.860Z","namespace":{"id":2259,"name":"sam","path":"sam","kind":"user","full_path":"sam","parent_id":null,"avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/755db8ssqaq50dcc9d189c53523b?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/sam"}}]
```

I am using python to parse the json and get the value of id.
I have tried the following **command** to do the same but got an error.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9999ayayayar66" "https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=demo_project" | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["id"])'
```

**Error:**

[image: Error]

Can anyone help me the correct python command to get the value of id.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Brilliant questions and you almost solved it yourself. I never thought of piping sys.stdin before. Thank you for that.

Comment: You welcome @PraysonW.Daniel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON contains an array of objects but you are treating it like it is a single object:

```
import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)["id"])
```

You're basically saying *"here is a collection of objects, give me the ID of the object"*.  It doesn't make sense.

If you assume you only ever want the ID of the first object in the array, you can use this:

```
import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[0]["id"])
```

Answer (score 4):

The root of you JSON object is actually an array, so you should get the first item out of it first:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9999ayayayar66" "https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/api/v4/search?scope=projects&search=demo_project" | python -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[0]["id"])'
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to write `print(json.load(sys.stdin)[0]["id"])` because json response is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tagged [Python Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/), your CURL command could be translated to:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '9999ayayayar66',
}

params = (
    ('scope', 'projects'),
    ('search', 'demo_project'),
)

response = requests.get('https://od-test.od.com/gitlab/api/v4/search', headers=headers, params=params)
```

Then you can get the id value from the [JSON Response Content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) with `response.json()[0]["id"]`. This uses the built-in JSON decoder to convert the JSON response to a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Requests is not part of python standard library and you may not always control/install it on-demand. Question here was about curl.

Comment: @Phil this question was tagged with python requests, you seemed to have missed that.

Comment: That's correct. I have not mentioned that and indeed, python Requests makes our life easier with json.